# ReferenceError: Discord is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, referenceerror

I've already searched around and i'm unable to find the answer to my dilemma. I'm running on node.js and javascript, but unfortunately i'm awful at coding because i'm just now starting out! please give me some tips if i've done anything wrong. anyway! Anytime someone tries to preform a command, this comes up, but my bot comes online.
[see here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBJSG.png) so, I have tried to change the code and my code seemingly looks like this;

```js
var Discord = require("discord.js")

const { promisify } = require("util");
const readdir = promisify(require("fs").readdir);
const Enmap = require("enmap");

var client = new Discord.Client();
```

Is there something i'm missing here? thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Looks like you're having trouble at the import stage. Did you already run `npm install discord.js`? (See [installation section of docs here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).)

Comment: yes! ty for the welcome. I have installed the `discord.js` now and even have tried uninstalling it. anything else that could be causing this problem! cheers!

Comment: Okay, so your import is working then. Could you share more code?

Comment: yup! heres a bit more.

`var Discord = require("discord.js")

const { promisify } = require("util");
const readdir = promisify(require("fs").readdir);
const Enmap = require("enmap");

var client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  client.user.setActivity('https://git.io/d.js-heroku', {type: 'WATCHING'});
});

client.config = require("./config.js");

client.logger = require("./modules/Logger");

require("./modules/functions.js")(client);`

Comment: Are you referencing `Discord` in any of your separate requires (like `config.js`)? You'll also have to import it in there. Not really sure what's going on otherwise.

Comment: how would i reference that in my config? using the same `var client = new Discord.Client();` code?

Comment: If you're referencing `Discord`, re-import it. If you're needing to access `client`, then you need to make some sort of function and pass the client into it. Like `export function configureClient.... configureClient(client);` Does that make sense?

Comment: how exactly would i do that? sorry for asking aaaa

Answer (score 1):

You are using
`var Discord = require("discord.js")`
so you should try to use `const` instead of `var` if you haven't tried this
`const Discord = require("discord.js")`

Comment: Can you edit the answer to explain how and why this should solve the problem?